# CSGO Mic Setup menu not working

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

When clicking in the settings, the Mic Setup button in bottom right side nothing happens, it doesn't let me edit any mic settings, and the people in-game say they can't hear me.

Comment: I did fix the mic via Realtek HD Audio Manager, but Mic Setup menu still don't work.

Comment: What Windows do You use or is it linux ?

Comment: Well, it works now, but I don't know what I did. Win8x64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem, here is a list of things you should do:

1. Update any drivers for your microphone/headset and update steam.
2. Check that the microphone is set to default in the sound manager.
3. Make sure in the steam settings that your microphone is turned all the way up.
4. Check if your microphone is chosen in the steam sound manager.
5. Check that a button is actually binded to your microphone.
6. Restart steam and your computer